# read an image (TIF image) from FTP Server

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, ftp, tiff

i wanna read an image (TIF image) from FTP Server and then view it 
i used to read from FTP server this code:

```
//CREATE AN FTP REQUEST WITH THE DOMAIN AND CREDENTIALS
                    System.Net.FtpWebRequest tmpReq =     (System.Net.FtpWebRequest)System.Net.FtpWebRequest.Create(filePath);
                    tmpReq.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(userName, password);
                //GET THE FTP RESPONSE
                using (System.Net.WebResponse tmpRes = tmpReq.GetResponse())
                {
                    //GET THE STREAM TO READ THE RESPONSE FROM
                    using (System.IO.Stream tmpStream = tmpRes.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        //CREATE A TXT READER (COULD BE BINARY OR ANY OTHER TYPE YOU NEED)
                        using (System.IO.TextReader tmpReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(tmpStream))
                        {

                            //read and view image


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

i need your help how to convert TIF image to Jepg or other type and also how to read TIF from FTP using my code

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Image](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.aspx) class to perform the conversion. Also make sure you dispose disposable resources such as network streams:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var filePath = "ftp://example.com/foo.tif";
        var request = WebRequest.Create(filePath);
        request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
        using (var response = request.GetResponse())
        using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (var img = Image.FromStream(stream))
        {
            img.Save("foo.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you can mention your path in first parmeter , like img.Save(@"d:\someFolder\foo.jpg",ImageFormat.Jpeg);

Answer (score 0):

See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/624df111-7e0b-4df1-8bb4-6060366ff51c) regarding TIFF-JPEG conversion.

You're on the right course - read the thread I posted and save your data using the proper Objects

EDIT:

Some further [reading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229711.aspx) as for the FtpClient from MSDN

Comment: i read it but still have a missing circle
how to get the image tiff from FTP as i read as Stream